# Popup bootstrap-confirmation problems

Tags: jquery, button, popup

I've got a problem with an popup from bootstrap-confirmation.min.js.
I've made a button to delete a picture, but before it deletes, you get a small popup under the button. With the options: Yes/Cancel.

While i'm clicking on cancel, and trying to click my button again, i have to click my button twice before it works again. The popup also doesn't close while i'm clicking outside the box. I can't find any information to resolve my problem.

Can someone here help me with it?
My button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-foto="<?php $data['fotoproduct']->foto2 ?>" id="delete_2" data-toggle="confirmation">
```

Verwijder

My code looks like this:

```
 $(function(){
        var removeFunction = function(id) {
            var number = id.split('_');
            var foto = $('#foto_' + number[1]).attr('href');
            var p_id = $('#hidden_field').data('p_id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "verwijderfoto",
                data: {foto: foto, p_id: p_id},
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#delete_' + number[1]).hide();
                    $('#load').fadeOut();
                    $('#foto_' + number[1]).hide();
                    $('.text_delete_' + number[1]).append("Geen foto");
                }
            });
        };
        $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
            title: "Weet u het zeker ?",
            backdrop: "static",
            btnCancelLabel: "Cancel",
            btnOkId: "test",
            placement: "bottom",
            onCancel : function(){
                $(this).confirmation('hide');
            }
        });
        $('#imgs > button').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('body').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', function(){
                removeFunction(id);
            })
        });
    });
```

Beside this file, i'm using the regular bootstrap-confirmation.min.js. Hopefully this is enough information.

I look forward to hearing your reply.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle to see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line at the beginning of bootstrap-confirmation.js

if(this.inState == undefined) this.inState = {};